# RadGrid FormTemplate: Don't want to view edit mode on page load

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, telerik-grid

Basically, I am using FormTemplate for my grid which works perfectly but When I always load my page, I always see the first row in edit mode. How I can change the mode to view mode? I mean: when I first load the page, all rows to be shown in tabular format and anytime I click on edit button, the formTemplate controls to be shown.

Hope I delivered my question comprehensively.

Comment: For more information, I have used this method for my grid: [Radgrid EditTemplate](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/edit-form-types/defaultcs.aspx) but this method displays edit mode by default when I load or refresh my page.

Comment: In the codebehind for that demo, they have: `protected void RadGrid1_PreRender(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack && this.RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items.Count > 1)
            {
                this.RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items[1].Edit = true;
                this.RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Rebind();
            }
        }`. Unless you have something similar in your code, the edit form should not show on page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is resolved: I removed below method and it did the trick.

```
protected void gridActivities_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        gridActivities.EditIndexes.Add(0);
        gridActivities.Rebind();
    }
}
```